# Dynamically canceling already sent BUYLIMIT order

Tags: mt4

I am using `OrderSend` like this

```
OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYLIMIT,Lots,100, 50,200,"",Magic,0,Red);
```

in this case, buy will be executed when price comes 100.

But I want to check one more layer when the price comes 100.

like this.

```
// when price comes to 100.
if (MacD > 0){buy cancel;}
```

Is this possible ? or `OrderSend` can not be canceled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Given your `OrderSend()` has created a **`BUY-LIMIT`** pending order:

your Broker has created a pending XTO-instruction on their books and indeed, once the Market-price ( `Ask` ) hits the set XTO-`OrderOpenPrice() == 100.0`, such Pending-Order turns executed at set price `== 100.0` without any other intervention, automatically.

This is a common procedure.

---

### Given you wish to do something else, once a price hits the set `100.0`:

well,
in this case, one should rather not use Pending Orders, as there is zero-chance to modify it as the price moves close to the Pending Order set `OrderOpenPrice()`.

There is a detailed specification about so called **`StopLevel`** and **`FreezeLevel`** distances from a set price, that prevents any such wished modification, cancellation or even remnoval from taking place, once the Market price wanders into these proximity zones.

So,
**either**
do not place the Pending Order ( and keep all the XTO operations based on XTO-s using the plain Market-Orders `{ OP_BUY | OP_SELL }` )
**or**
modify your Pending-Orders `{ OP_BUYLIMIT | OP_BUYSTOP | OP_SELLLIMIT | OP_SELLSTOP }` order-management policies, to take decisions during a price still being outside of the `MarketInfo()`-inspected StopLevel-zone and FreezeLevel-zones.

Comment: Thanks my basic idea was wrong, I should check every tickes and use  `OP_BUY | OP_SELL` as such.